# How to find the sum of this geometric serie: $ 3+ \sqrt3 + 1 + ...$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometric-series

I am trying to find the sum of this geometric series but can't find it:

$ 3+ \sqrt3 + 1 + ...$

The solution I get is:

$S=\frac{3(3+\sqrt{3})}{4}$

but the answer key shows:

$S=\frac{3\sqrt{3}(\sqrt{3}+1)}{2}$

This exercice is from a book called Pre-Calculus in a Nutshell. I could solve the other geometric series but this questio has a square root and I must be making a mistake when simplifying.

Here are the steps I took to find my solution, maybe you can see where it goes wrong?

The sum of a geometric serie is

$(S) = \frac{a}{1-r}$ when |r| < 1

$3*r=\sqrt{3}$

Therefore:

$r=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$

$|\frac{3}{\sqrt{3}}|<1 $ so I can use that formula

$a=3$

which gives me

$S=\frac{3}{1-\sqrt{3}}$

simplifying I get:

$S=\frac{3*(1+\sqrt{3})}{1-\sqrt{3}*(1+\sqrt{3})}$

$S=\frac{9+3\sqrt{3}}{1- (-3)}$

Simplifying more:

$S=\frac{3(3+\sqrt{3})}{4}$

Comment: $\sqrt{3} > 1$ so you wouldn't be able to apply the geometric series formula with that value.  Luckily, you made another mistake in computing $r = \frac{\sqrt{3}}3$ so you can redo it with that value.

Comment: Hi you are right, I made a mistake transcribing here, it should be $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$ and I corrected it in my post. I did all my calculation with that correct value and didn't get the correct answers. What am I missing?

Comment: @AlexFortin If you put the correct ratio, as per your last comment. You get the answer key's answer.

Comment: $S=\frac{3}{1-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}}$

Comment: g, I got it now, thank you everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed the common ratio was incorrect, it should be $\frac1{\sqrt3}=\frac{\sqrt3}{3}$

\begin{align}
S &= \frac{3}{1-\frac{\sqrt3}{3}}=\frac{9}{3-\sqrt3}=\frac{9(3+\sqrt3)}{9-3} =\frac{3(3+\sqrt3)}2 = \frac{3\sqrt3(\sqrt3+1)}{2}
\end{align}

Edit: Alternative working:

$$S=\frac{3}{1-\frac1{\sqrt3}}=\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt3-1}=\frac{3\sqrt3(\sqrt3+1)}{2}$$

Comment: Perfect example, that really helped. I couldn't see why he extracted the $\sqrt{3}$ on that last step but I guess it is obvious 3 can is the product of $\sqrt{3}$ Thank you!

Comment: Included a slightly different working.

Answer (score 1):

You also made a second error.  In your working $(1+\sqrt3)(1-\sqrt3)=1-(-3)$.  But actually $(1+\sqrt3)(1-\sqrt3)=1-(+3)$.

Here is a tip with geometric series:  when the series converges, its sum should have the same sign as the first term and be more than half as large in absolute value; thus if the first term were $1$ the sum could be $+3/5$ but not $+2/5$ or $-3/5$.